# Why image is not getting saved in media directory in django?

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to save the image in media/images directory and have done each and every neccosry step which is described below. But after all, I am not getting the image in my directory please someone guide me where is the problem. Thank You.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class students(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fathername = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact =models.CharField(max_length=20)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from home import views
from django.contrib import admin
from home import StudentViews
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings



urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("Add_Student", views.Add_Student, name="Add_Student"),
    path("display_students", views.Display_Student, name="display_students"),
    path("<int:id>", views.student_profile, name="student_profile"),
    #path("student/<int:id>/view", views.student_profile, name="student_profile"),

    path("Student_Home", StudentViews.StudentHome, name="Student_Home")
    
]

#this line is for media 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

In settings.py, I added the following lines of code.

```
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/images')
MEDIA_URL= "/images/"
```

**My Directory**

Student_Management_System

- home
- media/images
- templates
- static

**Note:** I have already installed Pillow.

**views.py**

Here is  my  view `Add_Student` that add the entry into database.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from home.models import students

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

def Add_Student(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST['lastname']
        fathername = request.POST['fathername']
        city = request.POST['city']
        country = request.POST['country']
        state = request.POST['state']
        zipcode = request.POST['zip']
        address = request.POST['address']
        contact = request.POST['contact']
        photo = request.POST['photo']

        Add_Student = students.objects.create(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, fathername=fathername, city=city,country=country, state=state, zip=zipcode, address=address, contact=contact, photo=photo)
        Add_Student.save()
        return redirect('Add_Student')
    else:
        return render(request, 'student/Add_Student.html')
```

Comment: Add your view class/function.

Comment: @JPG I have added views.py file, please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `MEDIA_ROOT`

```
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app_name/media')
```

You can read from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage) `point number 2`

> defining the `upload_to` option specifies a subdirectory of MEDIA_ROOT to be used for uploaded files.

Also make sure that you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`form attribute to your template as mentioned here in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the  that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Also a little change in `Add_student` view

```
photo = request.FILES['photo']

Add_Student.save() # NO need to use this. create() creates and saves the object at the same time.
```

You can read about this [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/503ee41497f346de27843a4ea976c57303c76558/docs/topics/http/file-uploads.txt#L33)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you noticed that I am using my own form rather than django built-in form. So in the upload_file() view, form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) request.FILES is used as described in the documentation. But in my case, where I have to use it?

Comment: Ok wait! Updating my answer

Comment: Thank you very much again. You are great.... It solved my problem. By the way, Django is very hard :D

Comment: Nope it's beautiful. Just stay with it. :)

Comment: Yes, I am working hard. Please keep in touch with me

Comment: please answer this question. need your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239324/how-to-submit-and-retrieve-data-in-one-view-in-django

Comment: Please answer this simple question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68334466/how-to-populate-onetoone-field-from-template-side-in-django