# Cannot assign "'1'": "staff.staff_type" must be a "staff_type" instance. Django Error in OneToOne field

Tags: python, django

I am working on a small django-python project which has two models "staff_type" and "staff". In the **staff_type** model, only designation and date fields are populated. And in the  **staff** model, there is OneToOneField relation of staff_type. Means whenever a user want to add staff first he/she will have to add staff_type and then in the staff module, user will choose the staff type (designation) from a select menu in which all the staff_type are shown respectively.

Now, whenever a user select any designation (staff_type) and fill the entire form, I want to store  the selected staff_type id in the **staff** model/table.

Note: I have tried this from django admin, and it works perfectly but I want to do the same work in my own designed templates.

**Modles.py**

```
class staff_type(models.Model):
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    entrydatetime = models.DateTimeField( auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

class staff(models.Model):
    staff_type = models.OneToOneField(staff_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fathername = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact =models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cnic = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    photo = models.ImageField()
    cv = models.ImageField()
    otherfiles = models.ImageField()
```

**views.py**

```
def add_staff_type(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        designation = request.POST.get('designation')
        salary = request.POST.get('salary')
        datetime = request.POST.get('datetime')
        
        add_staff_type = staff_type.objects.create(designation=designation, salary=salary, datetime=datetime, entrydatetime = dt.now())
        add_staff_type.save()  
        messages.info(request, "Staff type has been Added.")
        return redirect('add_staff_type')
    else:
        #fetching records from the database table
        display_staff_type = staff_type.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'staff/staff_type.html',{'display_staff_type':display_staff_type})

#this view is for fetching the designation column and displaying in the select tag
#and rendering add_staff html form
def add_staff(request):
    staff = staff_type.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'staff/add_staff.html', {'staff':staff})

#this view is for adding the staff 
def add_staff_view(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        staff_type = request.POST.get('stafftype')
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        fathername = request.POST.get('fathername')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        state = request.POST.get('state')
        zipcode = request.POST.get('zip')
        contact = request.POST.get('contact')
        cnic = request.POST.get('cnic')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
        cv = request.FILES.get('cv')
        otherfiles = request.FILES.get('photo')

        add_staff = staff.objects.create(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, fathername=fathername, city=city,country=country, state=state, contact=contact, cnic=cnic, zip=zipcode, address=address, photo=photo, cv=cv, otherfiles=otherfiles, staff_type=staff_type)
        add_staff.save()
        messages.info(request, "Staff has been Added.")
        return redirect('add_staff')
    else:
        return render(request, 'staff/add_staff.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),

    path("staff/add_staff_type", views.add_staff_type, name="add_staff_type"),
    path("staff/add_staff", views.add_staff, name="add_staff"),
    path("staff/add_staff_view", views.add_staff_view, name="add_staff_view"),

    
]
```

**add_staff.html**

```html
<form class="needs-validation" action="add_staff_view" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
               {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="card-body">      

        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom01">Staff Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="stafftype">
            {% for staff in staff %}
              <option name="stafftype" value="{{ staff.id }}" required>{{staff.designation}}</option>
            {% endfor %}

            </select>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom02">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="First name" name="firstname" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom03">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>         
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom04">Father Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="Father Name" name="fathername" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          
          </div>
          
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-row">

        

          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom05">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="City" name="city" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid city.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom06">Country</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom06" value="Pakistan" name="country" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid country.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom07">State</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom07" placeholder="State" name="state" >
          
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom08">Zip</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="validationCustom08" value="0000" name="zip">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom09">Contact</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom09" placeholder="Phone Number" name="contact" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid country.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom10">CNIC</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="validationCustom10" placeholder="xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x" name="cnic" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please provide a valid country.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Current Address" name="address">
          </div>
       </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="file col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label class="file-label" for="customFile01">Photo</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="customFile01" name="photo"/>
          </div>

          <div class="file col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label class="file-label" for="customFile02">CV</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="customFile02" name="cv"/>
          </div>

          <div class="file col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label class="file-label" for="customFile03">Other Files/Photos</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="customFile03" name="otherfiles"/>
          </div>
       
        </div>

        

          <div classs="form-row">
      
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Staff</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      
         </form>
```

I tried my best at the above code but it gives me the error.

**Error**

Exception Value:
Cannot assign "'1'": "staff.staff_type" must be a "staff_type" instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`staff_type` in `staff` model must be `staff_type` model instance so first get model instance

```
 s_type = staff_type.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('stafftype'))
 staff.objects.create(...,staff_type=s_type)
```

Or you can also assign fk directly like this.

```
  staff.objects.create(staff_type_id=request.POST.get('stafftype'))
```

And please try to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standards for writing python codes.

Note: It's better using django [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) and Also you can use built-in generic class-based [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) which will make your things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending number to Staff model into the field "staff_type". You either need to cast it to staff_type, or put an instance there

Comment: I didn't get it. Please describe it.

Comment: staff_type = request.POST.get('stafftype')

This part is taking id of staff_type from your request which is represented by integer.

then you have  add_staff = staff.objects.create(staff_type=staff_type) which creates the record. Here you pass your variable containing integer which you obtained from request. You need to cast it to staff_type model instance by Staff_type(staff_type), or get an instance by Staff_type.objects.get(pk=staff_type) and then pass it to object creation part.

Try this one:

add_staff = staff.objects.create(staff_type=staff_type(staff_type))

Comment: I added an instance before "if" condition in the "add_staff_view" that is "staff_type = staff_type.objects.get(pk=staff_type)" and added "staff_type=staff_type(staff_type)" in add_staff=staff.obejcts.create() and got this error... Exception Value: 
local variable 'staff_type' referenced before assignment