# Why django not storing files in media folder?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-settings

My `settings.py`

```
MEDIA_ROOT='/static/'

MEDIA_URL='media'
```

My `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns=[
#all routes
]

if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This code works fine many time but this is not working, I don't know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why image is not getting saved in media directory in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179323/why-image-is-not-getting-saved-in-media-directory-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `BASEDIR` and you are defining it wrong way.

Try this:

`Settings.py`

```
MEDIA_URL= '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Answer (score 0):

could it just be
urlpatterns += static

Comment: Yes, I have made the typo while writing the question, actually I already wrote this in my editor.